# AWS S3 Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: amazon-s3

The installed version of AWS doesn't support the encryption installed of the new bucket (A client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.) so I'm looking to update AWS-CLI as a result. However, this 502 error has me totally stumped. I'd tried everything I can think of. Both read the same config (key/secret) yet I have no idea why the newer aws-cli would give me the 502.

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.3.14 Python/2.7.5 Linux/2.6.18-274.el5 
$ aws s3 ls s3://analytics-Y/
                           PRE Client/
                           PRE Server/


$ /home/X/bcmp/bin/aws --version 
aws-cli/1.15.53 Python/2.7.5 Linux/2.6.18-274.el5 botocore/1.10.52

$ /home/X/bcmp/bin/aws s3 ls s3://analytics-Y/
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3.America', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /New_York.amazonaws.com/analytics-Y?delimiter=%2F&prefix=&encoding-type=url (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',)))
```

Any ideas of what I could try?

Comment: So... `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3.America', port=443)` what is `s3.America`?  It looks like you have a proxy server configured, somewhere, and your cli versions are probably using different config files, which is why one exhibits this behavior, but not the other.

Comment: And where does "New York" come from? What have you configured as your Region? It should come from: [AWS Regions and Endpoints - Amazon Web Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)